# Installation of matlab

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, matlab

> Is there anyway to install the latest version of Matlab from Ubuntu's Software repository?
>
> Or is there any other software in Ubuntu that may work same as Matlab?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. on my pc.

Comment: Have you read this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: Or you could just install octave with `sudo apt-get install octave`. Then run it in GUI mode with `octave -gui`. It runs the same code as Matlab but is an open source software.

Comment: @Ron the description is very complicated. I installed Matlab from CD, then the `matlab-support` package from the repository, which do everything almost automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Matlab can be installed in Ubuntu in a easy way.So if use of Matlab is not strictly compulsory you can use other softwares just like it which are of open source.

One of that is Octave.You can install it using the command

> sudo apt-get install octave

Comment: No matlab is not compulsory.Ok will surely checkout Octave.Thanks for the reply bdw.